Docker angular-nginx 502 Bad Gateway
I've been trying to run my angular app on nginx with docker but I can't get it running. This are the last modifications I tried:
My docker file:
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY package.json .
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @angular/cli@17
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 4200

My docker-compose.yaml file:
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
    context: .
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

My default.conf file:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

The command i've been using to run my compose file:
docker-compose up --build
The error I get when trying to connect:
502 Bad Gateway
I couldn't get through it

Looks like your Angular app is only accepting connections from localhost, which since it is in a container means that it only accepts connections from within the container.
You need to allow it to receive requests from outside too. Your npm start command can be updated to do this.
A suitable package.json might look like this:
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

You can ignore most of that. The critical bit is the definition of the start script which should be something like ng serve --host 0.0.0.0, where the --host 0.0.0.0 argument is the key bit!

I was convinced that it was a problem related to the way docker configure the container DNS to communicate with its host, while it was an Angular misconfiguration since the beginning. Thanks
